# What are some popular free/open-source charting controls?

Tags: programming, charts

Recently I've tried SciChart and VisiBlox - beautiful charting tools. Are there any free or open-source tools for visualizing charts in C#?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: The best free one I have come across in C# space is OxyPlot.

Comment: At my firm, after the number-crunching we provide the data as RESTful to the UX that takes care of the charting with D3.js - might be off-topic but it may still be an option to consider.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript web / mobile, you can use [LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/). 
It's free for personal use.

[image: LightningChart JS Github project]

For WPF / C# desktop, [LightningChart Trader](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-trader-net/) library comes handy, with built-in technical indicators and drawing tools.

[image: LightningChart Trader]

It not free, entirely though, but comes as a free value-added library for all LightningChart subscribers.

I'm the tech lead of LightningChart.